# Excel "pull" function from closed files, but for a range instead of a single cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the code in the comments found at http://numbermonger.com/2012/02/11/excel-pull-function-creating-dynamic-links-to-closed-workbooks/. I pasted it below. It's been modified to make it work for me, so some of the variables might be a little redundant. Anyway it works great to pull a value from another workbook that is closed on the server. But I need to be able to pull ranges. I passed in ref1 and ref2 and tried to make it work that way, and also tried to pass in the range as one variable like:

```
=SUM(MAGIC($B$9,"$C$22:$C$25"))
```

But that didn't work either. I just get a "#VALUE!" error. Here is the code I am using, derived from the link above:

```
Public xlapp As Object

Private Function magic(ByVal filename As String, ref1 As String, ref2 As String) As Variant

Dim arg As String
Dim path As String
Dim file As String
Dim count As Integer
Dim tempcount As Integer

count = 0
While (Left(Right(filename, count), 1) <> "\")
count = count + 1
Wend

count = (count - 1)
tempcount = Len(filename)
tempcount = (tempcount - count)
path = Left(filename, tempcount)

count = (count - 1)
file = Right(filename, count)

count = 0
While (Left(Right(file, count), 1) <> "]")
count = count + 1
Wend

tempcount = 0
tempcount = Len(file)
tempcount = tempcount - count
file = Left(file, tempcount)

If Dir(path & file) = "" Then
magic = "File not found..."
Exit Function
End If

If arg2 = "" Then
    arg = "'" & filename & "'!" & Range(ref1).Range("A1").Address(, , xlR1C1)
Else
    arg = "'" & filename & "'!" & Range(ref1).Range("A1").Address(, , xlR1C1) & ":" & Range(ref2).Range("A1").Address(, , xlR1C1)
End If

magic = xlapp.ExecuteExcel4Macro(arg)

End Function
```

And in my workbook open section I have the code below,

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Set xlapp = CreateObject("Excel.application")
End Sub
```

And again the problem is that it works just fine for getting one value:

```
A1 = C:\users\sam\[test.xlsx]sheet1
B1 = magic(A1,"$H$7")   ->   returns the value from cell H7 in the other workbook
```

But not for a range:

```
A1 = C:\users\sam\[test.xlsx]sheet1
B1 = sum(magic(A1,"$H$7:$K$7")   ->   returns a VALUE error
```

Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: +1 for the function name ;) and sorry but you can't grab a range from a closed workbook this way. I would suggest using ADODB.Recordset if you want to grab a whole Range.

Comment: Even using ADODB you may have problems depending on what you intend to do with the range values. As a general rule (although there are ways around this) a UDF function called *from the worksheet* is not capable of putting values in *other* cells, i.e., you can't use a function in one cell to "fill" an entire range of cells.

Comment: You could possibly add a Loop in this function to *get* the other values (i.e., `For each cl in arg.Cells...`) but you'd still be left with the problem I mention in previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
Public xlapp As Object

Private Function magic(ByVal nameAndPath As String, ref1 As String, rowOffset As Integer, colOffset As Integer) As Variant

thisFPend = InStrRev(nameAndPath, "\", Len(nameAndPath))
thisFP = Left(nameAndPath, thisFPend)
thisFNend = InStrRev(nameAndPath, "]", Len(nameAndPath)) - 2
thisFN = Mid(nameAndPath, thisFPend + 2, thisFNend - thisFPend)

If Dir(thisFP & thisFN) = "" Then
magic = "File not found..."
Exit Function
End If

'Multiple values
arg = "SUM('" & nameAndPath & "'!" & Range(ref1).Address(, , xlR1C1) & ":" & Range(ref1).Offset(rowOffset, colOffset).Address(, , xlR1C1) & ")"

'Single value
'    arg = "SUM('" & nameAndPath & "'!" & Range(ref1).Address(, , xlR1C1) & ")"

magic = xlapp.ExecuteExcel4Macro(arg)

End Function
```

I've eliminated the loops for finding the file name & path.  Instrrev is a wonderful function!

The trick here is that you can't pull multiple range values into a single cell like you're trying to do, you can only pull a single value.  So I've used sum in the argument to be passed into ExecuteExcel4Macro.

Instead of specifying a range in "ref1" I've included a "rowOffset" argument and, for kicks, a "colOffset" argument.  So, ref1 is the start of the range you want to sum and the rowOffset is the count of rows you want to sum.  Therefore, instead of passing the argument ["$A$2:$A$5"] to sum four rows, you would pass ["$A$2", 4].